# PHP Error syntax

Tags: php

I have a [web site](http://dreamworld-pvp.fr/) and my problem is about the section "Voter".

When we vote, we doesn't have the gift and the error come about my line 121:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in /home/pvpdream/public_html/voter/recompenses.php on line 121
```

I give you the script:

```
<?php

        if ($_SESSION['out'] == true) 
        {
                $inputString = $_SESSION['Pseudo_String'];
                $pseudo = $inputString;

                $selection = $bdd -> prepare('SELECT * FROM joueurs WHERE user_pseudo = :user_pseudo');
                $selection -> bindParam(':user_pseudo', $inputString);
                $selection -> execute();    

                $MonPersonnage = $selection -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                $NomPersonnage = $MonPersonnage->user_pseudo;

                #### POINTS
                $NbrPoints = $MonPersonnage->user_points;
                $NbrVote = $MonPersonnage->vote;
                $ApresVote = $NbrPoints + $Points_par_vote;
                $vote = $NbrVote +1 ;


                #### TEMPS
                $date = time();
                $HeureVote = $MonPersonnage->date_vote;
                $EcartMinutes = ($date - $HeureVote)/60;

                #### IP
                $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

                    if ($EcartMinutes > 180)
                    {

                        if($_GET['verification'] == "items" && $_GET['serveur'] == 'f') 
                        {
                            $serveur = 'f';

                            $update = $bdd->prepare('UPDATE joueurs SET date_vote = :date_vote, vote = :vote WHERE user_pseudo = :user_pseudo');
                            $update -> bindParam(':date_vote', $date);
                            $update -> bindParam(':vote', $vote);
                            $update -> bindParam(':user_pseudo', $NomPersonnage);    
                            $update -> execute();

                                $update = $bdd->prepare('UPDATE vote_ip SET date_vote = :date_vote WHERE ip = :ip');
                                $update -> bindParam(':date_vote', $date);
                                $update -> bindParam(':ip', $ip);
                                $update -> execute();

                                ##################################### Probabilités 

                                     $query = $bdd->prepare('SELECT SUM(p) AS somme FROM probabilites');
                                     $query->execute();
                                     $string = $query->fetch();
                                     $nbr_items = $string['somme'];

                                     $query = $bdd->prepare ("SELECT * FROM probabilites WHERE serveur = '".$serveur."'");
                                     $query->execute();

                                        $prob = 1000;
                                        $rand = mt_rand(0, $prob);                      

                                    $items = array ();
                                        while($resultats = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
                                        {
                                            $items[$resultats->quantite.'|'.$resultats->nom.'|'.$resultats->commande.''] = $resultats->p / $nbr_items;
                                        }
                                        asort($items);

                                        $i = 0;
                                        foreach ($items as $name => $value) 
                                        {
                                            if ($rand <= $i+=($value * $prob)) 
                                            {
                                                $item = $name;
                                                break;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    list($quantite, $nom, $commande) = explode("|", $item);     

                                   # Exécution des requêtes items

                                        $commande_exp = explode(" ", $commande);        

                                                if($commande_exp[0] == 'POINTS')
                                                {
                                                    $requete = str_replace("POINTS ", "", $commande);       
                                                    $VoteBoutique = $NbrPoints + $requete;

                                                echo '<br /><div class="alert alert-success"><b> Succès</b> : '.$pseudo.' vous venez d\'obtenir le cadeau suivant : <b> '.$quantite.' '.$nom.' </b>.</div>';
                                                    $update = $bdd->prepare('UPDATE joueurs SET user_points = :user_points WHERE user_pseudo = :user_pseudo');
                                                    $update -> bindParam(':user_points', $VoteBoutique);
                                                    $update -> bindParam(':user_pseudo', $pseudo);   
                                                    $update -> execute();

                                                $connexion_1->call("runConsoleCommand", array("broadcast ".$pseudo." vient de gagner ".$quantite." ".$nom." en votant pour le serveur."));
                                                /*$connexion_2->call("runConsoleCommand", array("broadcast ".$pseudo." vient de gagner ".$quantite." ".$nom." en votant pour le serveur."));
                                                $connexion_3->call("runConsoleCommand", array("broadcast ".$pseudo." vient de gagner ".$quantite." ".$nom." en votant pour le serveur."));
                                                $connexion_4->call("runConsoleCommand", array("broadcast ".$pseudo." vient de gagner ".$quantite." ".$nom." en votant pour le serveur."));
                                                $connexion_5->call("runConsoleCommand", array("broadcast ".$pseudo." vient de gagner ".$quantite." ".$nom." en votant pour le serveur."));
                                                $connexion_6->call("runConsoleCommand", array("broadcast ".$pseudo." vient de gagner ".$quantite." ".$nom." en votant pour le serveur."));
                                                $connexion_7->call("runConsoleCommand", array("broadcast ".$pseudo." vient de gagner ".$quantite." ".$nom." en votant pour le serveur."));
                                                $connexion_8->call("runConsoleCommand", array("broadcast ".$pseudo." vient de gagner ".$quantite." ".$nom." en votant pour le serveur."));
                                                */}

                                                else
                                                {
                                                echo '<br /><div class="alert alert-success"><b> Succès</b> : Vous venez d\'obtenir le cadeau suivant : <b> '.$quantite.' '.$nom.' </b>.</div>';
                                                    $commande = str_replace('pseudo_var', $pseudo, $commande);
                                                    $connexion_1->call("runConsoleCommand", array("".$commande.""));
                                                    $connexion_1->call("runConsoleCommand", array("broadcast &c&lFélicitation &b&l".$pseudo." vient de gagner ".$quantite." ".$nom." en votant pour le serveur.));

                                                }

                         $_SESSION['out'] = false;

                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo '<br /><div class="alert alert-danger">Vous devez attendre 180 minutes afin de pouvoir revoter.</div>';
                    }
                }
                elseif ($_SESSION['out'] == false)
                {
                    echo '<br /><div class="alert alert-danger"><b> Erreur</b>: Votre récompense a déjà été obtenue.</div>';
                }

?>
```

Comment: The syntax highlighting shows where the missing quote is: `$connexion_1->call("runConsoleCommand", array("broadcast &c&lFélicitation &b&l".$pseudo." vient de gagner ".$quantite." ".$nom." en votant pour le serveur.));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the error from the syntax highlighting in your question. It's this line:

```
$connexion_1->call("runConsoleCommand", array("broadcast &c&lFélicitation &b&l".$pseudo." vient de gagner ".$quantite." ".$nom." en votant pour le serveur.));
```

You need an extra `"` at the end, so it would be:

```
$connexion_1->call("runConsoleCommand", array("broadcast &c&lFélicitation &b&l".$pseudo." vient de gagner ".$quantite." ".$nom." en votant pour le serveur."));
```

Comment: that would be:
$connexion_1->call("runConsoleCommand", array("broadcast &c&lFélicitation &b&l".$pseudo." vient de gagner ".$quantite." ".$nom." en votant pour le serveur.));"

Comment: I post a second time. I tried and they tell me:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ')' in /home/pvpdream/public_html/voter/recompenses.php on line 119

Have you another suggestion?

Comment: I updated my answer to show where the `"` goes.

Comment: Thank you very much man! I love you :p